# How do you find a value between multiple named number ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have values in a certain column as follows.

```
Rank Score
A    10
B    24
C    35
D    88
E    192
.
.
.
```

And so on. There are far too many entries to do an IFS statement and the numbers have an arbitrary difference between levels (A to Z). If I have a number, say 85, as per the info above, it should be rank C (between 35 and 88).
I want to check which rank it falls under. I need a single formula so I can apply it across another sheet with multiple scores that need to be ranked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use floating `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, {B:B, A:A}, 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

for arrayformula do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, {B:B, A:A}, 2, 1)))
```

[image: 0]

also see alternatives: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**